# In this sentence, does “devoir” (must) refer to “une obligation” or “une probabilité”?

Tags: sens

In this sentence,

> Tu es hors de toi, tu **dois bien** t'en rendre compte.

which means “You're beside yourself. You **must** be well aware of that.”, the word "dois" translates into "must". But does the sentence mean either:

- an obligation: “You're beside yourself. You **have to** realise that.”
- or a probability: “You're beside yourself. You **certainly** realise that.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of **bien** before **devoir** changes the meaning of **devoir**, you almost understood it in your comment on jlliagre's answer.

If you add an adverb on **devoir**, such like **bien**, it will mean a strong probability rather than an obligation.

Without any adverb in this case, **devoir** means an obligation.

> Tu dois t'en rendre compte, tu vas droit dans le mur sinon

Here is a few adverbs changing the meaning of **devoir** :

> Sûrement
>   Tu dois sûrement t'en rendre compte
>
> Probablement
>   Tu dois probablement t'en rendre compte

But some adverbs insist on the obligation :

> Vraiment
>   Tu dois vraiment t'en rendre compte

The verb **falloir** can be used in this case to build an unambiguous sentence. Here it means an obligation :

> Il faut que tu t'en rende compte

Answer (score 2):

That means a strong probability, i.e. "you are so furious that it is very unlikely for you not to realize it".

Comment: When "devoir" is used with "bien", does "devoir" almost always mean a strong probability rather than un obligation? Thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily, e.g. *Tu dois bien te tenir à l'école* means an obligation.

Comment: I think it is all about tone. If the sentence is interrogative, it means a high probability, but if it is affirmative (aggressive ?), it is an obligation... You may also say "tu dois bien t'en rendre compte" as an advice or something like that (even if uncommon)